# AWS Elastic beanstalk create EC2 with wrong subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, subnet

On an existing environment in Elastic beanstalk made by Terraform with *aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:DeploymentPolicy* at *RollingWithAdditionalBatch* an EC2 instance was previously built with the configured vpc and the correct subnet.
A new one is being build. The VPC is ok but the subnet differ from the configured one in Elastic beanstalk.

Do you have any idea? If yes do you know how to fix it?
Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after change Availability Zones in EC2 Auto Scaling Groups.